# Kotlin BigDecimal multiplication wrong results

Tags: kotlin, bigdecimal

I need to use BigDecimal for some computation but am a bit surprised by the behaviour:

```
val thousand = BigDecimal(1000)
val fee = BigDecimal(0.005)
println(thousand * fee)
```

You'd expect the console to contain `5` but the result is `5.000000000000000104083408558608425664715468883514404296875000`

I know that I can limit the precision and do some rounding with `setScale` but the real question is Why is this needed in the first place. This result is obviously wrong.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Kotlin rules but in Java the literal 0.005 in `BigDecimal(0.005)` is converted to a `double` and this double becomes the constructor argument. Now, 0.005 cannot be **exactly** represented as a Java double, so you've already lost the game before you even get to BigDecimal. Use string arguments like `BigDecimal("0.005")`, these can be converted into the exact value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely to be with the construction of the `fee` BigDecimal. This is taking a `double` value and converting it to a `BigDecimal`. Unfortunately, some fairly simple decimal fractions are impossible to precisely represent as `double`s or `float`s, and this constructor for `BigDecimal` will take that imprecise `double` as its value.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-):

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, appearances notwithstanding.

The way around this is to use the String constructor, which gets round the issue of having to convert "via" a `double`.